# Multiple OneDrive icons in Windows Explorer

Tags: onedrive

[image]

I'm not sure why I have multiple OneDrive icons. When I click on the folder icon, it opens a new window with all of my OneDrive files. I dragged the folder onto Quick Access section and it turned into a cloud. What's going on with the icons, and which one should I keep?

Comment: You have two. You also have pinned OneDrive to Quick Access which can easily be unpinned. The other folder can also be removed.

Comment: @Ramhound Why is the folder icon OneDrive there and how did it pop up there?